# New to ubuntu, experiencing problems

Tags: software-installation, search, partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 TLS.
While I took my time and read a lot of stuff to familiarize myself, there are still some problems that are continuing to puzzle me.

I installed ubuntu on a partitioned Drive (exactly 20 GB which is more than enough) using Wubi. It asked me how much space I wanted to allocate for ubuntu and I chose 19GB which was max for the size.

My problems right now are:

1) I installed skype, which I can access and do everything using ubuntu, but Ubuntu Application Manager does NOT show it on installed apps. Searching for skype returns 0 results, while already-installed stuff can be seen. However if I search my system using for "skype" it will return with a result. What am I doing wrong?

2) How can I move my installed apps to a different partition? I am planning to use 20GB just for ubuntu and install the rest of the apps to a different partition of >150GB

I really did not find any clue about these.
If it helps I used to be a Win7 user

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Concerning question #2, you can't -- at least, not easily. Ubuntu follows the Unix model of file placement, which is pretty rigid about where certain things go. For instance, user binaries (program files) almost always reside in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, or `/usr/local/bin`, depending on what type of program they are. What's more, the package files that you install put the binaries in those locations, and moving them from their original locations is inadvisable because doing so would break the package system, complicating software updates.

What you can do is to mount different partitions at certain locations. For instance, you could have a separate partition for `/usr` or `/usr/local` to isolate binaries on their own partitions. This is most easily done when you install Ubuntu, though. It's also something that's not recommended for novices because you need to understand disk space needs, the rules for what can be split off into separate partitions, etc., and novices generally lack such expert-level knowledge.

Note that Linux's structured disk model is different from that in Windows, which has historically encouraged many different ways of using the disk, including more mixing of user and OS data. Some experienced Windows users have developed their own systems for organizing data, which might or might not translate well into the Unix/Linux world. Furthermore, Linux doesn't draw as much of a distinction between the initial OS installation and subsequently-installed applications as is the case in Windows, so isolating applications that you install yourself seldom makes much sense.

You don't say in your question why you want to put your applications on a separate partition. Depending on your needs, there may be ways to do what you want within the Unix/Linux model. For instance, some people split off `/home` into a separate partition. Because most user files go in subdirectories of `/home`, this has the effect of isolating user files from OS files, which can simplify backup and certain types of re-installation tasks.

Another complication in your case is that you did a WUBI install. WUBI installs Linux strangely, using a file in a Windows partition instead of a separate Linux partition. WUBI is being abandoned and is generally not a recommended way to install Linux any more.

Overall, I'd say you might be best off by wiping out WUBI, repartitioning the disk, and doing a conventional dual-boot installation. When you do this, do *not* use the Windows disk partitioner to create partition(s) for Ubuntu; just use it to shrink the Windows partition and leave free space for Ubuntu. Use the Ubuntu installer to create new partitions for Ubuntu.

Comment: The reason I want to move my apps is because of space. So do you think I should merge my 20gb partition to main drive? I don't mind reinstalling. There are more than enough space. I have drive that is 180Gb and 100 Gb is free. If I install ubuntu there, will my files stay there or will it be cleaned? This is my case: I have 3 partitions, C: for windows, D: as a warehouse with no OS, H: for Ubuntu which is 20gb. What do you mean by not using Windows disk partitioner? I use software to partition disks, can I do that? I wanna merge H: and D: to install ubuntu but will it wipe data on D:?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about your disk layout. For instance, if partitions are next to each other, you can usually shrink one and grow the other into that space. In your case, though, you really should get rid of WUBI and start from scratch, which means shrinking the Windows partition to make room for *new* Ubuntu partition(s).

Comment: I already uninstalled wubi,
But my question is different:
1) I do not even need to touch windows, because I have a 180GB partition with no OS installed in, Will actual Ubuntu installation ask me how many GBs to allocate for ubuntu? If so, how much should I choose? 1-30GB
I will probably get rid of windows but I have to use both for a while to make sure ubuntu can actually replace windows ;)

Comment: If you have an empty 180GB partition that you intend to give to Ubuntu, then Ubuntu will use it all; however, you can repartition that space to give some of it back to Windows in one way or another. It sounds like you need a primer on partitions. Try [this one](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/4269/1) (old but still basically applicable) or [this one.](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2010/12/partitioning-basics/)

Comment: I'm really confused. Why doesn't ubuntu just take let's say 5ish GB upon installation and use the rest as I add content? Did I understand your point right? If I install ubuntu on 180 GB partition, will it take 180 GB at once? And If I give it a smaller partition it will run out of space. I want ubuntu to BE ABLE to use as much as it needs. For example I install it the initial size is 10GB then as I install applications it just increases... What should I do, I will install the regular way not Wubi or else

Comment: Like I said, you need to read a basic primer on partitions. A basic understanding of partitions will answer your questions.

Comment: I am aware of primary partitions :)   The drive am intending to install ubuntu is a primary partition not extended. What I want is NOT putting ubuntu any limit on how much it can use. It should use as much as it needs. My question is if I install it on 180 GB Primary partition will it take 180GB at once? Like reserve it all?   Thanks a lot for your assistance ;)